# Ubuntu Problems with Firefox 44 and Firefox 45

Tags: 12.04, firefox, video

I am a user of Ubuntu 12.04 x64 almost since its release and i can say that i am very satisfied with it.

But recently i ran into two problems both concerning Firefox which is my main browser.

When Firefox was updated to version 44 i had serious problems with videos and Firefox crashed every time a video was present in the page i visited.

This problem is also mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/712402/newly-installed-firefox-43-crashes-when-videos-are-played). I followed the instructions and the problem was fixed until the next update of Firefox where the problem returned. I have also seen [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/729960/firefox-44-crashing-on-certain-videos) and i even found [this](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=2979515) in Mozilla and submitted my feedback, but unfortunately i had no success in finding a solution.

Of course there are no such problems in the corresponding version in windows which i use for work.

My solution was to use FF43 or, since i plan on upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 when it is released, i used an extra disk and installed ubuntu 15.10 just to see if i still had such a problem.

The result was that in Ubuntu 15.10 FF was working ok until version 45 in which videos are OK but one of my main add-ons, (x-notifier) stopped working properly to the point that it is unusable. Again the only viable solution for me is to use FF44.

Again, no such problems in the windows versions of FF and my FF profile is always the same.

Now, i am aware that i maybe mixing two separate problems in one post and i apologize if it is so. But as an end user i find it hard to not combine these two, because to me it seems as there is a pattern involving FF and Ubuntu.

As i am planning to upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 anyway, it is not a big problem for me to wait for a couple of months and in the meantime use FF44 or FF43.

But i am afraid that there will be something wrong with FF and Ubuntu 16.04 also !

If someone is aware of anything that might help it will be great.

Thanks in advance for any feedback submitted, and i am always grateful both to all the people who make these awesome pieces of software and to the people answering questions !

Comment: I think the add-on problem may be because of FireFox's API changes - add-ons not working in a newer version is fairly common.

Comment: This sounds similar to my current issues - Firefox and Thunderbird freezing/crashing on both Kubuntu 15.10 (now 16.04) and Thunderbird on WinXP. My FF on Kubuntu will always now crash with a video page from Digg (haven't checked others) - FF 48.0 on WinXP is stable; Thunderbird on 38.5.0 seems stable there now after a fresh profile. Thunderbird 38.6 on Xenial has long freezes and some crashes where it takes down my X (lots of Xorg.log errors) and system can only be brought back with magic SysReq reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is a problem with Firefox 45 and 46, I had the same. Firefox 47 seems to work much better, you can download the binaries from here: https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/45.1.0esr/linux-x86_64/en-US/